# Anchor tag that calls a div won't scroll enough on phone

Tags: html, css, layout, scroll, anchor

I've got a really basic issue that you may be able to help me with. I'm trying to use an anchor tag to navigate to a certain div on my website. Now while this works perfectly on my pc. For some reason when it comes to using it on phone it doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom of the div like on PC. This ends up cutting off one of the images I have at the bottom of that div. FYI, Chrome is being used for these tests.

```
<style>
#aboutMe img{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
</style>

<a href = '#aboutMe'>Click me</a>
<div id = 'aboutMe'>
  <img src = 'someimage.png'>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I actually realised that the code was working just fine. But  the issue was with chrome, where chrome changes the height of the window by shrinking the URL bar when scrolling down the page.